# UIManager.put("Panel.opaque", false); does not work

Tags: java, swing

Setting UIManager.put("Panel.opaque", false); does not work.
I need to call panel.setOpaque(false); for each panel.

what can be the problem?

Comment: try UIManager.put("Panel.opaque", Boolean.FALSE); (although shouldn't make any difference) and that should be done before setting layout (I think).

Comment: Not all properties are controlled by the UIManager.

Comment: First of all, what's the Look and Feel used by your application? UIManager properties have different treatments (or no treatment at all) depending on the installed LAF.

Comment: default look and feel for Mac.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom `JPanel` class and use it instead of JPanel.

```
class MyJPanel extends JPanel{

  public MyJPanel(){
     setOpaque(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [`JComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) instead? It is [non-opaque by default](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that constant when i do

```
    UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
    Set<Entry<Object, Object>> entries = defaults.entrySet();
    for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : entries) {
        System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " = ");
        System.out.print(entry.getValue() + "\n");
```

Comment: Its there on Apple's JVM: TabbedPane.background = com.apple.laf.AquaNativeResources$CColorPaintUIResou    rce[r=238,g=238,b=238]
Panel.opaque = true
PrintingDialog.abortButtonDisplayedMnemonicIndex = 0

Answer (score 0):

Since the method deals with default values, you have to put it at the very beginning of your program to make it work, or probably before calling other GUI related methods.  The only thing that should come before it is locale.